# Save XML parsed by JSDOM as a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, jsdom

I can parse XML like this:

```
import JSDOM from "jsdom";
const myXml = "... some xml loaded from somewhere ...";
const dom = new JSDOM.JSDOM(myXml);
```

I was really surprised when I googled *"jsdom save xml"* and I got nothing. I thought JSDOm is one of the most popular libraries for XML manipulation.

In one answer, I've seen this:

```
window.document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

That produces garbage code for some reason, for example it converts:

```
<Node>
   <Child attr="attr"/>
   <Child attr="attr"/>
   <Child attr="attr"/>
   <Child attr="attr"/>
</Node>
```

to

```
<Node>
   <Child attr="attr">
   <Child attr="attr">
   <Child attr="attr">
   <Child attr="attr">
   </Child></Child></Child></Child>
</Node>
```

It also starts the document with:

```
<html><head></head><body><globe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Note that `Globe` is the root element of the source XML. It also produces everything in lower-case.

Comment: You might need to tell JSDOM that it's not parsing HTML.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it interpreted the document as HTML. It wasn't immediately apparent, since the selectors and such worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method of saving the document was correct. But the method of parsing is wrong. `JSDOM` requires HTML and creates an instance of browser DOM. And it must be used as such, so the steps are the same as when parsing XML in browser:

```
// Create empty DOM, the imput param here is for HTML not XML, and we don want to parse HTML
const dom = new JSDOM.JSDOM("");
// Get DOMParser, same API as in browser
const DOMParser = dom.window.DOMParser;
const parser = new DOMParser;
// Create document by parsing XML
const document = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

// save the xml after modifications 
const xmlString = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (and easy) way to render xml is passing { contentType: "text/xml" } property to JSDOM initializer.

With Content Type:

```
let testString = `<root><child1/><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></root>`

const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const dom = new JSDOM(testString, { contentType: "text/xml"});

const xmlString = dom.window.document.querySelector("root").outerHTML;

console.log(testString);
console.log(xmlString);
```

outputs:

```
<root><child1/><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></root>
<root><child1/><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></root>
```

But without content type (defaults to text/html):

```
let testString = `<root><child1/><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></root>`

const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const dom = new JSDOM(testString);

const xmlString = dom.window.document.querySelector("root").outerHTML;

console.log(testString);
console.log(xmlString);
```

renders as:

```
<root><child1/><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></root>
<root><child1><child2><grandchild>name1</grandchild></child2></child1></root>
```